# Take a value from earlier in the page and use it in a form

Tags: html, django, forms, post

Say I have a html form:

```
                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="submit" name="create" class="buttonsmall"> Create</button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="selected[]" value="" />
                </form>
```

This is in a div that is much farther down my page (at the bottom). I have established `selected[]` further up the page in another div. Due to my css and positioning I'd rather keep the two elements separate, but I'd love to send that data with this button. How do I get my hidden element to reference the `selected[]` from further up the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send the hidden element, you can either just move 'form' tag above the hidden element and make sure the hidden element is an input type
Or you would recreate it again in the form and, like you said to set the type to hidden.